# how to call a JavaScript function in the callback URL (jsOAuth + twitter + non-PIN OAuth)

Tags: javascript, oauth, dom-events, twitter-oauth

Learning about OAuth, I came across a big question.
How to call a JavaScript function in the callback url with jsOAuth?

When you click Connect to twitter, the login screen opens, then the Twitter authorize APP and after he simply calls the callback URL.
I would like to close this window and call a JavaScript function on the page that originated.

[See my tests](http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/twitter.html)

### Code

```
oauth = OAuth({
            consumerKey: srv.key,
            consumerSecret: srv.secret,
            requestTokenUrl: srv.request_token,
            authorizationUrl: srv.authorize,
            accessTokenUrl: srv.access_token,
            callbackUrl: "http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/twitter.html"
        });
```

### Screenshots

I took some Screenshots will explain better:

[image: Authorize]

**after**

[image: Callback]

I asked this [same question on GitHub](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth/issues/19#issuecomment-3339587);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
oauth = OAuth({
        consumerKey: srv.key,
        consumerSecret: srv.secret,
        requestTokenUrl: srv.request_token,
        authorizationUrl: srv.authorize,
        accessTokenUrl: srv.access_token,
        callbackUrl: "http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/callback.html"
    });
```

and in callback.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * call parent window function and close
 */
function callback() {
    window.opener.functionName(querystring('token'));
    window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="callback()">
</body>
</html>
```

To be tested.